# Entity changed to `Detached` state due to severed relationships to its parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 5.0.11. My models looks like:

```
Entity_A:
 Id
 List<Entity_B>

Entity_B:
 Id
 Entity_A
 <shadow>Entity_A_Id
```

when I'm trying to set in code:

```
var a = new Entity_A();
dbContext.Add(a);
dbContext.SaveChanges()

...

var b = new Entity_B();
b.Entity_A = a;
```

I get this *Entity changed to `Detached` state due to severed relationships to its parent entity*

It only works if I remove a list from Entity_A and update to just *.WithMany()*:

```
Entity_A:
 Id

Entity_B:
 Id
 Entity_A
 <shadow>Entity_A_Id
```

Is it an intended behavior that makes me change one-to-many relationships in a way so that they should be always initiated from parent entity only unless no collection of child entities exists on parent?

If I add child to parent collection it works just fine. Getting rid of shadow FK property doesn't help either.

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies somewhere in your "...".  (aka the code you don't provide) You need to provide a complete and reproducible example to give people the best chance at helping you.  

Provided you are working with the same DbContext and the same tracked object references it doesn't matter whether you go `newA.Bs.Add(newB)` or `newB.A = newA`, EF will resolve the two.